# PIG generates blank lines

Tags: hadoop, null, apache-pig, hdfs, cloudera

I have a simple pig job that generates one column of data. To eliminate blank lines from the output, I wrote the following command:

```
items = FOREACH inputs GENERATE item;
items = DISTINCT items;
items = FILTER items BY ($0 IS NOT NULL);
items = FILTER items BY NOT IsEmpty(TOBAG($0));
STORE items INTO '$output/items';
```

While I try to eliminate NULL and empty entries, I still get blank lines in the output files on HDFS.

It is worth noting when I replace the last line (i.e. STORE) with,

```
DUMP items;
```

The terminal output does not show the blank output line.

Any comments on the root-cause of this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself.

It turns out the Pig parser turned blank parsed input into a newline. So, the following ended up working (see the third line):

```
items = FOREACH inputs GENERATE item;
items = DISTINCT items;
items = FOREACH items GENERATE ($0=='\n'?NULL:$0);
items = FILTER items BY ($0 IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT IsEmpty(TOBAG($0)));
STORE items INTO '$output/items';
```